# Why aren't the submit and reset buttons displayed?

Tags: php, html

I have made a form. Why aren't the submit (*enviar*) and reset (*restablecer*) buttons displayed? If I remove the PHP code, they do appear. Why?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Documento sin título</title>
</head>

<body>
      <div> 
<form action="" id="noti-form"method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="noticia">

Antetítulo de la Noticia<br />
      <input type="text" name="ante" size="70" id="ante" class="inputbox" />
      <br />

Título de la Noticia<br />
      <input type="text" name="titulo" size="70" id="titulo" class="inputbox" />
      <br />

Subtítulo de la Noticia<br />
      <input type="text" name="sub" size="70" id="sub" class="inputbox" />
      <br />

Autor:<br />
      <input type="text" name="autor" size="30" id="autor" class="inputbox" />
      <br />
      Texto de la Noticia<br />

        <div align="center">
            <textarea id="elm1" name="noticia" class=".noticia" rows="15" cols="80" style="width: 80%"></textarea></div>
      <br />

        <input type="file" name="foto" id="foto" />
     <br />
<?php
    echo '<select class="chosen" name="tags[ ]"  multiple="true" style="width:400px;">';

    $query=$database->tags();
    foreach ($query as $data)   {   
        echo  '<option  value="'.$data['tag'].'">'.$data['tag'].'</option>';
    }
    echo'</select>';
?>

    <input type="submit" name="enviar" value="Enviar" class="button" />   
    <input type="reset" name="button" id="button" value="Restablecer" class="button" />
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you should probably use `htmlspecialchars()` when echoing out the `$data['tag']` parts, perhaps one of these includes a character which is causing the following HTML to not display

Comment: any errors? try using `<?php` instead of the shortag (`<?`) aswell

Comment: you also don't need to have your first and last `echo`s at all they can be just HTML

Comment: what comes up if you run the php code on its own?

Comment: No, No errors, the form is displayed without the buttons send and resent... :S ( I tried whit <?php and with htmlspecialchars() but dosen't work

Comment: What is the actual output source of the above code? You might have a die/exit somewhere in your code. You might want to check the tags function.

Comment: if I run the php code without php , the buttons send ans reset are displayed

Comment: Hello sir, could you edit your answer and put the full file's content here?

Comment: the source page are this it.. , I have just this into the body

Comment: That's really strange, could you please use another web browser?

Comment: in other browser it's the same.. dosen't appears

Comment: can we see your css? You may have something like: `button { display: none; }

Comment: without CSS file.. the results are the same.. jajaj it's very strange!!!

Comment: I thnink that the PHP code is opening some HTML tags which aren't closed subsequently.

Comment: I've tried your code with jsFiddle and all buttons appear...that's weird

Comment: but.. with jsFiddle, maybe don't simulate the php.. therefore it's probably  work (i think)

Comment: Can you load your page (with the php code) then press CTRL+U in your browser (if you're on windows) then copy and paste the source code of the generated page here?

Comment: So the problem comes from PHP, and this is already a good information ;)

Comment: if I taste php code outside the html, <option> fields are shown, therefore, I think the php code works

Comment: As @Meds said can you pleas post the source code of your generated page?

Comment: Forgive ME! add missing include connection to the database within the HTML code

Comment: Haha despistado no problems.